# PHP Why do variables have to be pre-defined before a loop?

Tags: php, loops, variables, scope

Why do PHP variables need to be pre-defined before a loop in order to use it inside of (and subsequently outside of) the loop?

```
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
echo $source;
```

Shows "undefined variable" $source

```
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
    $source2 = '';
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source2 .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
echo $source2;
```

Returns only the last item in the variable but there is no undefined variable

Seems weird to me that it almost acts like a variable scope issue.

Comment: Not a scope issue; you just can’t _append_ anything to _something_ that doesn’t exist. And in your second example, you are setting the variable to an empty string _in_ every loop iteration – you have to do it _once, before_.

Comment: well in php you can, it will complain, but do it anyway. good-old-php

Comment: Made a big change on the examples because I wasn't sure if the examples i used actually demonstrated what I was trying to express.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are trying to concatenate a string to something that's not a string (or at least not yet) by doing:

```
$source .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
      //^ this dot means concat.
```

And in your second example, you are resetting your variable to an empty string in each iteration, the declaration should be outside, before the loop instead:

```
$source2 = '';
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){   
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source2 .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
echo $source2;
```

As @drew010 stated in his comment, the variable will be actually created by php but you will get the notice displayed (if you have your php settings so that they will be shown).

Comment: And to elaborate on the OP, technically it doesn't have to be declared before the loop.  `Undefined variable` is just a notice.  The end result is that the variable gets created and appended to with a side effect of a PHP notice being generated.  Doing this is bad practice so you should declare source as an empty string before going into the loop.

Comment: Thanks! I've added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Also, https://3v4l.org/cZL7O shows no error for the array append from over 150 different versions of php 4.3-7.0

Comment: Made a big change on the examples because I wasn't sure if the examples i used actually demonstrated what I was trying to express.